# Import .txt file from one directory to an excel file with a specific beggining on each line

Tags: excel, vba, import

I need help to import a specific file in .txt to excel, but only import specific lines with a specific begginnin tex, like '1234' or 'FPC9'.

```
Sub IMPORTAR2()
    Dim myDir As String, fn As String, txt As String, a(), n As Long, i As Long, ff As Integer
    myDir = "C:\Users\epontes\Desktop\TDFA 13228 CDP\" '<- Mude de acordo com a necessidade
    fn = Dir(myDir & "*.*")
    Do While fn <> ""
        ff = FreeFile
        Open myDir & "\" & fn For Input As #ff
        Do While Not EOF(ff)
            Line Input #ff, txt
            If InStr(Left(text, 4), "1234") > 0 Then
            n = n + 1: ReDim Preserve a(1 To n)
            a(n) = Split(txt, vbTab)
        Close #ff
        fn = Dir()
    Loop
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("a1")
        For i = 1 To n
            .Offset(i - 1).Resize(, UBound(a(i)) + 1).Value = a(i)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? ("I need help" is not a question).

Comment: To add to @BigBen, is there a specific line that isn't working as expected? Is there a situation in which your code breaks?

Comment: The VBA code breaks in: The first 'Loop'

I want to import from a .txt file into excel a specific line with a specific beginning (exemple: 123, but line by line into a pecific ws.

Comment: My guess would be that the error occurs when you attempt to write a 2 dimensional array into a single element of an already 2 dimensional array. Get rid of the `Split` and do the splitting when you write to the sheet. Or just dump everything to column A and then use the text to columns built into Excel.

Comment: Are the files very large  > 100M  and are they ASCII or Unicode. ?

Comment: The files are at the most 3Mb, i need a code to import all the lines from a directory (all files) to an excel file ws to column A line by line with a specific begginnig. Im very new to vba, the code above was search in the fórum, but i cant put it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an END IF and LOOP statement missing and the variable here should be txt

```
InStr(Left(text, 4), "1234") > 0
```

Corrected and now hopefully working as you intended

```
  Sub IMPORTAR2()
      Dim myDir As String, fn As String, txt As String, a(), n As Long, i As Long, ff As Integer, j As Long
      myDir = "C:\Users\epontes\Desktop\TDFA 13228 CDP\" '<- Mude de acordo com a necessidade
      fn = Dir(myDir & "*.*")
      Do While fn <> ""
          ff = FreeFile
          Open myDir & "\" & fn For Input As #ff
          Do While Not EOF(ff)
              Line Input #ff, txt
              If InStr(Left(txt, 4), "1234") > 0 Then
                  n = n + 1: ReDim Preserve a(1 To n)
                  a(n) = Split(txt, vbTab)
              End If
          Loop
          Close #ff
          fn = Dir()
      Loop
      MsgBox n & " Matched"
      With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("a1")
          For i = 1 To n
              For j = 0 To UBound(a(i))
                .Offset(i, j + 1) = a(i)(j)
              Next j
          Next
      End With
  End Sub
```

But no need to build an array, just write the lines out as you find them

```
  Sub IMPORTAR()

      Dim myDir As String, fn As String, txt As String, a As Variant
      Dim n As Long, i As Long, ff As Integer
      myDir = "C:\Users\epontes\Desktop\TDFA 13228 CDP\" '<- Mude de acordo com a necessidade
      fn = Dir(myDir & "*.*")

      With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("a1")
      Do While fn <> ""
          ff = FreeFile
          Open myDir & "\" & fn For Input As #ff
          Do While Not EOF(ff)
              Line Input #ff, txt
              If StrComp(Left(txt, 4), "1234", 1) = 0 _
                 Or StrComp(Left(txt, 4), "FPC9", 1) = 0 Then
                 n = n + 1
                 a = Split(txt, vbTab)
                 ' output
                 For i = 0 To UBound(a)
                   .Cells(n, i + 1) = a(i)
                 Next
              End If
           Loop
           Close #ff
           fn = Dir()
      Loop
      End With

      MsgBox "Finished"
  End Sub
```

Comment: Five Stars.

How can I import de text (1234) to sheet 2 and the code Ex.FPC9 to sheet 3 ?

Comment: Simplest way would be have 2 macros with a single StrComp()  in each and change the With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(?) to suit.

Comment: Thanks for the help.